# Appending From a Dictionary to a List

Tags: python

I am currently working on a program where a user can order a pizza. I am having some issues with the best way to take specific value from a dictionary and put it into a list that I can eventually use to give the customer a final total.

**What my question is: How would I take the user's input, match it with the 'key' and append the 'value' into a list that can be later used for users final total.**

Here is the dictionary I have currently:

```
sizePrice = {
    'small': 9.69, 
    'large': 12.29, 
    'extra large': 13.79, 
    'party size': 26.49
}
```

An example that I have written:

```
class PizzaSize():
    """" Takes the customers size requested and returns total cost of that pizza size"""

    sizePrice = {
        'small': 9.69, 
        'large': 12.29, 
        'extra large': 13.79, 
        'party size': 26.49
        }

    ordered_size= []

    def size(self):
        self.size_wanted = input("What size pizza would you like? ")
        self.size_wanted = self.size_wanted.title()
        customer_size = self.size_price[self.size_wanted]
        odered_size.append(customer_size)

order = PizzaSize()

order.size()
```

I know the above code is incorrect, however, I am looking for anything that will get me in the right direction.

Comment: You're turning the input into "Title Capitalisation", but all of the size keys are lower case. Use `self.size_wanted = self.size_wanted.lower()` instead.

Comment: If you are taking the user input from command line, sanitize it. Guarantee it's what you expect, force it to lower/upper, etc. Never trust input directly. From there, you can do an `in` check to see if the input key is in your dictionary. If it is, retrieve it, else handle the error how you see fit.

Comment: you have an `AttributeError` because your class does not have a member `size_price`. Either correct this to `sizePrice` or change the name of your dictionary to `size_price`

Comment: Note that you also have a typo in "odered_size", and with your current setup you should be referring to it as "self.ordered_size" since just specifying ordered_size will have Python searching (and failing to find) a local variable called "ordered_size", whereas you declared it as a member variable

Comment: TBH I tried to read your question 3 times and it was REALLY hard :/ Do you think you can maybe add an example for a desired outcome? Also, might be helpful to focus your question 'I am looking for anything that will get me in the right direction' isn't specific enough. Do you want review? Do you want us to help you find your problem in the code?

Comment: You probably want to give a message if the size entered is one available.  Something like:  `if self.size_wanted.lower() in sizePrice:`  <good entry>  `else:` <bad entry>

Comment: Actually the subject line of this question is misleading to the intent.  You really just want to select item from a dictionary based on user input.

Comment: @theshopen My over all question was: How would I take the user's input, match it with the 'key' and append the 'value' into a list that can be later used for users final total. I know there were other issues in my code so any other advice is appreciated. I apologize if my question was not straight forward. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not thoroughly tested, but here's one way to do it with comments explaining the thought process: (Note that you could have achieved the same with much less code, but writing code with simple objects and clearly defined properties makes it much easier to maintain larger applications and is hence a good habit to get into)

```
# We'll ask the user for a number since those are easier to input,
# especially in console applications without auto-complete/other visual feedback.
# Ideally I would suggest looking into Enums,
# but I'm guessing you're just starting out so this should suffice

size_mappings = {
    1: "small",
    2: "large",
    3: "extra large"
}

# Note that we could have mapped numbers to prices as well,
# but it's not very readable. Readability is supreme. Enums solve this problem.

cost_mappings = {
    "small": 6,
    "large": 10,
    "extra large": 12
}

# I like my objects simple, and designing classes etc. comes with practice
# but intuitively I would want Pizza as one object with a single size property
# Cost could also have been a property but this application is simple enough
# and I didn't see a need to make a part of the object,
# especially since we already have a mapping declared above.

# In general you want objects to have properties and methods to access
# those properties. A pizza can have a size,
# and the way you get the pizza's size is by calling get_size()


class Pizza():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def set_size(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size()

    def get_cost(self):
        return cost_mappings[self.size]

# Once again, intuitively an order can have multiple pizzas, so we
# construct an order object with a list of pizzas.
# It's an object with a property to add pizzas to it,
# as well as compute the order total (which is what you wanted to do).
# To compute the total, we go through all the pizzas in the order,
# access their cost and return the total.


class Order():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pizzas = []

    def addPizza(self, pizza):
        self.pizzas.append(pizza)

    def getTotal(self):
        total = 0
        for pizza in self.pizzas:
            total += pizza.get_cost()
        return total

# start processing the order
order = Order()

# This is an infinite loop, implying the user can continue adding pizzas
# until they are satisfied, or dead from heart disease (*wink*)

while True:
    try:
        # Need a way to exit the loop, here it is by pressing q and then enter
        response = input("What size pizza would you like?\n\
(1: small | 2: large | 3: extra large)\n \
Press q to finish order and compute the total\n"
                         )
        # This is where we check if the user is done ordering
        if response == 'q':
            break
        # The input is taken in as a string, 
        # convert it to an integer for processing
        # since our dictionary has integers as keys
        size_wanted = int(response)
        # A few things going on here.
        # Lookup the string version of the size we stored in the dictionary
        # Construct a pizza with a specific size, "small", "large" etc.
        # The pizza object gets stored inside the order object 
        # through the addPizza method
        size_wanted = size_mappings[size_wanted]
        order.addPizza(Pizza(size_wanted))
    except:
        print("An error occurred, please try again")

# The beauty of OOP, the logic to compute the total is already there.
# Call it and be done. 
print("Your total is: ", "$" + str(order.getTotal()))
```

Let me know if you'd like further clarifications, happy to help!

Clarification as requested (check comment for explanation):

If you wanted to put the while loop inside a function, you could do this:

```
def run():
    while True:
    # code here

# Single function call in the entire file
# But you must have atleast one to make sure
# SOMETHING happens. Every other function can 
# be called inside run(), the "main" function
run()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to construct this. I have been coding/programming for about 4 months and I feel like I need to begin developing actual programs. As started looking for a starting point, I realized OOP is something that I really need to have down. This really helped. Thank you again.

Comment: Of course! OOP's awesome (albeit verbose), I haven't found a better way to organize code haha. More work to write, but way, way easier to read and modify

Comment: One question that I do have for you, does every thing need to be in a class or a function?  Or does it depend on the program you are writing? Like the infinite loop you created for ordering more pizzas, could that be placed in a function?

Comment: Everything can be placed inside a function, but you will need at least one function "call" that's outside of all functions. When you run this script with Python, it goes through each line and evaluates it. Most functions it will read and store somewhere, so that it knows what to do with them once they are called. Implying if everything you have is in a function, Python will read the entire file and exit without doing anything interesting. As long as you have one call at the end of the file to atleast one function (the so-called "main" function), everything else can be called from within that.

Comment: Alright last question lol Would the new function 'run' be placed on the inside of the class Order(). Or would that go on the outside?

Comment: Although you could place it as a member function and call it like so: order = Order().run(), thinking in terms of OOP it doesn't make much sense for an order to "run". In this context, the "run" function is outside of all classes/functions i.e. when you define it, you will have no indentation, similar to when we defined the variable cost_mappings, the Pizza class, Order class etc. you can also define a function in the same "scope", I believe the module scope. Basically translates to "run" not being dependent on anything, whereas putting it inside Order makes it dependent on the Order class

Comment: Thank you for all of the help and clear explanation! I've learned more through this conversation then any of the books I have purchased. Thanks again!